# Proper way to store ckeditor value (html markup) in database? (trouble with line break)

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, newline

I'm using ckeditor for the first time and I'm using php to store the value of the ckeditor to a mysql database:

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
```

When I use mysql_real_escape_string before inserting into the DB it adds \r\n all over in the html from ckeditor. This is whats stored in the Database:

```
<p>Here is a line</p>
\r\n
<pre class=\"code-python\">name = &quot;Bob&quot;
\r\n
last = &quot;Smith&quot;
\r\n
full = name + &quot; &quot; + last</pre>
\r\n
<p>And another line</p>
\r\n
```

This is what I see when I echo it back to the browser:

> Here is a line
>
> rn
>
> name = "Bob"rnlast = "Smith"rnfull = name + " " + last
>
> rn
>
> And another line
> rn

Note that I **do** need to maintain the line breaks in the pre tags so I can't simply strip all of the line breaks.

This is what I'd like to see:

> Here is a line
>
> name = "Bob"
>
> last = "Smith"
>
> full = name + " " + last
>
> And another line

Comment: I should note that by not using mysql_real_escape_string I get back exactly what I want and expect, but I don't want to insert into the DB without it.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to your code: `$content = str_ireplace('\r\n', '', $content);`

So your code should now read:

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$content = str_ireplace('\r\n', '', $content);
```

I tried it and it works.

Comment: Use `str_ireplace("\r\n", '', $content);` instead.